# Almacenar funciones en clases

Tags: c++, loops, matrices, array

tengo el siguiente ejercicio de realizar una clase que calcule varias de las propiedades de una función matemática.

> Considérese una función `y=f(x)` definida en un intervalo `[a,b]`. Se desea muestrear esta función. Con este fin, se almacenará en un vector los valores de `x` `y` en otro los  valores de `y` correspondiente a cada valor de `x`. Este problema persigue crear una clase que  permita almacenar la función muestreada y llevar a cabo determinados cálculos: primera derivada, segunda derivada, máximos y mínimos relativos.
>
> Con este fin se pide:
>
> Diseñar una clase (que no implementar) que almacene una función muestreada, su primera y segunda derivada, y permita hacer determinadas operaciones.  Para ello debe constar de:
>
> Atributos que permitan almacenar *x*, *y*, *y’* y  *y’’*
>
> Un constructor al que se le pase como parámetro una función `y=f(x)`, un intervalo `[a,b]`, y el número de muestras `n`, y cree y almacene  *x*, *y*, *y’* y  *y’’*

Intenté empezar la clase así pero me trabé:

#### Iintentando hacer el apartado a)

```
class function{
private:

vector_item_t* x_; // x  abajo os dejo la clase vector_t  en la que me base
vector_item_t* y_; // y
vector_item_t* y1; // y'
vector_item_t* y2; // y''

public:

/*b) constructor */ function(¿?)

}
```

Me trabé en el segundo apartado cómo hago el parámetro que me calcule la imagen de x? al tratarse de vectores no sé cómo habría que programar la derivada primera y segunda, porque no se trata de polinomios que están ordenados según su grado.

Agradezco cualquier idea.

la clase `vector_t`

```
typedef double vector_item_t;
typedef unsigned short int vector_inx_t;

class vector_t {
private:
    vector_item_t* v_;
    vector_inx_t sz_;
public:
    vector_t (vector_inx_t n);
    ~vector_t (void);
    void mostrarVector(void);
    vector_item_t get_vector_item(vector_inx_t i);
    void set_vector_item(vector_inx_t i, vector_item_t it);
    vector_inx_t get_sz(void);
};
```

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es la pregunta :O

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster el desglose para que se entienda mejor

Comment: Me trabé en el segundo apartado cómo hago el parámetro que me calcule la imagen de x?                                                                             
            al tratarse de vectores no sé cómo(esto es otra duda) habría que programar la derivada primera y segunda, porque no se trata de polinomios que están ordenados según su grado.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster quedaron claras las preguntas?

Comment: La verdad es que no. Me da la sensación que preguntas: "*¿Qué debo hacer para resolver este ejercicio?*" y de ser así, la respuesta sería: "Hacerlo"... en el código que has pegado hasta ahora no hay ni una sola implementación así que no se qué has intentado para abordar el problema que tienes y por lo tanto no puedo usarlo para inferir tu pregunta; definitivamente aún no se cuál es la pregunta.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster el enunciado dice que no hay que implementar... es todo declararivo

Comment: A ver si lo entiendo... ¿el ejercicio es de diseñar y estás pidiendo a la comunidad de SO que te haga el diseño?, si es así (que no me queda claro) ¿Crees que aprenderás algo si los demás hacen tus ejercicios?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster     calmate tio, por que escribes con cierto aire de superioridad? en ningun momento pido que me hagais el ejercicio, haces algo reprobable  y me atribuyes esto "¿Qué debo hacer para resolver este ejercicio?"

Comment: Estoy calmadísimo, de hecho, el que parece que se enerva eres tú. Si no quieres que malinterprete tus intenciones tan sólo debes hacer que tu pregunta sea clara, tras dos horas y varios comentarios, habiendo descartado que no quieres que te hagan el ejercicio aún no se qué estás preguntando (y apuesto a que otros usuarios están igual). Seguramente en tu cabeza está muy clara tu duda, pero los demás no estamos en tu cabeza, aclara la pregunta, ayúdanos a ayudarte.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster me voy a centrar en un solo aspecto, mi duda básica es cómo pasar como parámetro al constructor  de la clase function  una función ¿se puede pasar como parámetro al constructor una función?

Comment: "*¿se puede pasar como parámetro al constructor una función? *" Por supuesto, puedes pasar cualquier objeto o tipo básico como parámetro ya sea por copia, puntero o referencia. ¿Qué necesitas que reciba el constructor?

Comment: @AER Te comento brevemente, PaperBirdMaster es un experto en C++ y una persona que ayuda regularmente en este y otros temas a los usuarios, te sugiero leas nuevamente [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y evites sea cerrada o con puntuación negativa. Lo que se busca es que las preguntas sean de utilidad para tí y otros usuarios, trata de especificar lo que deseas y tendrás la ayuda necesaria.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster  necesito pasar como parámetro al constructor una funcion que calcula la imagen de x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entiendo bien el enunciado, el ejercicio consiste en una clase que, dada una función, la muestree en `n` pasos en un intervalo cerrado entre `a` y `b`, para ello es necesario:

> Un constructor al que se le pase como parámetro una función `y=f(x)`, un intervalo `[a,b]`, y el número de muestras `n`.

Así pues, necesitarás pasar una función que devuelva un valor y reciba un valor, suponiendo que tanto retorno como parámetro sean de tipo `double` estamos hablando de funciones que tengan la misma firma que esta:

```
double funcion(double parametro) {
    double resultado;

    // hacer cosas...

    return resultado;
}
```

Siendo `parametro` el valor de `x` y el retorno de `funcion` el valor de `y`.

#### Punteros a función.

C++ es un [lenguaje de tipado fuerte](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipado_fuerte) y [estático](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_tipos#Tipado_est.C3.A1tico), esto implica (entre otras cosas) que todo (incluido las funciones) tiene un tipo subyacente, los tipos de las funciones de C++ siguen el siguiente formato: `retorno([parámetros...])`, así que el tipo de una función que recibe un `double` y devuelve un `double` sería `double(double)`.

Una vez conocido el tipo con el que queremos trabajar, podemos usarlo como parámetro, este es un ejemplo de un objeto que guarda una función:

```
struct funcion
{
    // Tipo de la funcion que recibe y devuelve double
    using tipo_funcion = double(double);

    // El constructor recibe una funcion que recibe y devuelve double
    funcion(tipo_funcion *parametro) :
        miembro{parametro}
    {}

    // El miembro almacena una funcion que recibe y devuelve double
    tipo_funcion *miembro;
};
```

Se puede usar así<sup>1</sup>:

```
int main()
{
    // Instancia que recibe la funcion coseno
    funcion f(std::cos);

    // Muestra 1 ya que es el valor de coseno de 0.
    std::cout << f.miembro(.0);

    return 0;
}
```

#### [Objeto función](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Como alternativa al puntero a función se puede usar un objeto función:

```
struct funcion
{
    // El constructor recibe un OBJETO FUNCION que recibe y devuelve double
    funcion(std::function<double(double)> parametro) :
        miembro{parametro}
    {}

    // El miembro es un OBJETO FUNCION que recibe y devuelve double
    std::function<double(double)> miembro;
};
```

La ventaja de el objeto función respecto al puntero a función es que éste puede almacenar [lambdas](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) y [funtores](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funtor), cosa que no puede hacer el puntero a función<sup>2</sup>, puede usarse así:

```
int main()
{
    struct funtor
    {
        double operator()(double d) { return d+d; }
    };

    funcion f([](double d){return d*d;});
    funcion g(funtor{});

    // Muestra .25 (.5 al cuadrado de la lambda) y 1 (el doble de .5 del funtor)
    std::cout << f.miembro(.5) << ' ' << g.miembro(.5);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Tu caso.

Para acabar de cumplir con el enunciado, necesitarás tres parámetros adicionales (dos para el intervalo y uno para el muestreo):

```
struct funcion
{
    funcion(std::function<double(double)> parametro, double inicio, double fin, double muestras) :
        miembro{parametro}
    {
        const double rango = fin - inicio;
        const double paso = rango / muestras;

        for (double a = inicio; a <= fin; a+= paso)
            muestreo.push_back(miembro(a));
    }

    std::function<double(double)> miembro;
    std::vector<double> muestreo{};
};
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[[Wandbox]三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ORVPnaHf09cIl1qF)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>Se pasa función pero se almacena puntero, las funciones tienen conversión implícita a puntero-a-función.

<sup>2</sup>Si (y sólo si) la lambda no captura valores, puede guardarse en puntero-a-función.